# Is there an alternative to object-fit: cover work in IE / EDGE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, frontend

Is there any alternative for the image to be proportional using the `<img>` tag?
The only one I found was `object-fit: cover;`, but is not functional for browsers Edge and IE9 +.

```
<div class="fixing-imagem">
   <figure>
      <img [src]="professor.imagem" class="foto-card" [style.background-position]="center">
   </figure>
</div>
```

My foto-card class:

```
.card-b .foto-card{
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-size: cover !important;
  border: 5px solid #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #8896A9;
}
```

My fixing-img:

```
.fixing-imagem {
  text-align: center;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: Possibly, but it's hard to come up with something without knowing the context.  Can you provide the HTML for the `<img>` tag and its wrapper(s)?

Comment: Not for img elements. You would have to use a background image with background size cover. I usually just set the width of the image to 200% for IE though.

Comment: Hi @JosephMarikle. Update my post!